# Need an OSX cd to reset admin password

Tags: macos, password

Issue - father in-law has alzheimers (early but impacting)
Wants files from Apple laptop and can't remember password(s)
Shop who set it up for him wants $$$s to unlock and reset and I said what a lot of BS, but they didn't supply an OS disk with the machine so can I (or he if there is something he can do) get an OS disk to reset the admin password?
PS. This is a first time foray for me into the world of Apples - he wants the "family tree" files.....
Any ideas - inbetween times we are scouring bits of paper with notes and old passwords etc.....
D.

Comment: What version of OSX are you using?

Comment: If you can't tell what version of OSX you have, it might also be helpful if you can tell us about the MacBook. Does it have a DVD drive built in?

Answer (score 5):

Although the bmike's answer will probably work, I suggest to try something more leightweight first. [This article](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/reset-forgotten-admin-password-mac-osx/) describes the procedure:

1. Boot your Mac's Recovery Partition by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> at startup
2. Go to `Utilities` > `Terminal`
3. Enter `resetpassword`
4. In the GUI select the disk and user and enter a new password.
5. Press `Save`. (Reset of home directory should not be necessary)

[image: Reset Password Tool]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a cd or dvd. That shop could have done you a solid and shown you single user mode.

Power off the Mac. Hold command S and follow the article below up to the two commands: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT2600

```
fsck -fy /  
mount -uw /
```

Then do these two commands exactly as written - spaces and punctuation count:

```
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
halt
```

Power up your Mac and then make a new account with a name like "rescue admin". This account can be used to reset the passwords of any other accounts.

Comment: Whoa @bmike! You are giving dangerous advice to an obvious newbie...

Comment: What's dangerous @n1000 about the steps that Apple Documents? The OP is clearly astute enough about computers to know to not pay an opportunistic repair shop.

Comment: :) Maybe you should add a notice that `rm` is quite dangerous, especially in  single user mode